# How to run a command on PersistentVolume creation?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-statefulset

I have a `StatefulSet` which looks like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  ...
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  — metadata:
      name: www
    spec:
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

It will create a `PersistentVolumeClaim` (PVC) and a `PersistentVolume` (PV) for each `Pod` of a `Service` it controls.

I want to execute some commands on those PVs before the `Pod` creation.

I was thinking to create a `Job` which mounts those PVs and runs the commands but how do I know how many of PVs were created?

Is there a kubernetes-native solution to trigger some pod execution on PV creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is [InitContianer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/).

You can add it to a spec of your `StatufulSet`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name:  web
spec:
...
  spec:
    initContainers:
    - name: init-myapp
      image: ubuntu:latest
      command:
      - bash
      - "-c"
      - "your command"
      volumeMounts:
      - name: yourvolume
        mountPath: /mnt/myvolume
```

Comment: Won't `InitContainer` execute on every deployment? I want to execute only on PV creation.

Comment: It will execute on each container start, but you can manage that situation by a flag file on your volume to mark it as "processed", just create a file "processed" in the root of the volume. Unfortunately you cannot somehow run anything between volume creation by PVC and pod starts, because that is a fully async process and moreover some of volume provides even not create a volume until the first mount. Also, you can create something like a custom script/controller etc. but the way with Init Container is much more straight and clear.